# Bootstrap navbar doesn't collapse when i press the button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with my bootstrap navigation. It won't collapse when I press the button and I don't figure it out what is the problem. I also include at the bottom of my html page `jquery` and `bootstrap.min.js`.

```xml
<section>
  <div class="header-section">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class=" navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                <!-- end button -->
            <a class="pull-left logo" href="#" title = "Return to the homepage">
              <img src="img/RoundLogo.png" alt="Color Architects">
            </a>
            <!-- end logo -->
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-collapse" role = "menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" role = "navigation">
              <li><a href="#">Why us?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Case studies</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Portofolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Who we are?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- end menu -->
        </div> 
        <!-- end container -->
      </nav>
      <!-- end navbar -->
    </div>
    <!-- end container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end header -->
</section>
<!-- end section -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. I didn't put the correct path to my jquery file.